# JSON String has wrong format

Tags: java, json, string

im trying to create a string from a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject Msg = new JSONObject();
Msg.put("Type", 1);
Msg.put("Values", Arrays.asList("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"));
Log.v("MSG", Msg.toString());
```

After trying to get the String, the List of String is shown like this:

```
{"Values":"[Value1, Value2, Value3]","Type":1}
```

But shouldn't it be like this?:

```
{"Values":[Value1, Value2, Value3],"Type":1}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which one of the myriad of JSONObject classes are you using? Where is its documentation?

Comment: This code produces `{"Type":1,"Values":["Value1","Value2","Value3"]}` for me, which seems to be fine (I'm using `org.json.JSONObject`).

Comment: Im Using org.json. Hmm thats weird, when i tried it was always marking the array as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSONArray`

```
JSONObject Msg = new JSONObject();
Msg.put("Type", 1);
Msg.put("Values", new JSONArray(new Object[] { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"} ));
Log.v("MSG", Msg.toString());
```